# Scroll con 2 linearLayout con diferentes fondos parpadea - ANDROID JAVA

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente layout de mi Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryGreen">

        <include layout="@layout/actionbar_toolbar" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/transfer_int_title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size_big" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
            android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
            android:persistentDrawingCache="all"
            android:animationCache="true"
            android:drawingCacheQuality="auto"
            android:background="@color/backgroundViewGeneric"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:hint="@string/originAccount"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorAzulNew"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/page_margin_bottom_small"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_white">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/originAccount"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/page_layout_height" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:hint="@string/interbank_benef_bank"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorAzulNew"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/page_margin_bottom_small"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_white">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="99"
                    android:lines="2"
                    android:textSize="13sp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:hint="@string/benef_account_type"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorAzulNew"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/page_margin_bottom_small"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_white">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/benef_account_type"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/page_layout_height" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:hint="@string/benef_account1"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorAzulNew"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/benef_account"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="25"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:hint="@string/benef_name"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorAzulNew"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/benef_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="25"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:hint="@string/docType2"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorAzulNew"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/page_margin_bottom_small"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_white">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/docType"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/page_layout_height" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:hint="@string/benef_doc"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorAzulNew"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/benef_doc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:hint="@string/benef_relationship"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorAzulNew"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/benef_relationship"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="25"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:hint="@string/benef_city"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorAzulNew"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/benef_city"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="25"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:hint="@string/benef_address"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorAzulNew"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/benef_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:hint="@string/amountToTransfer"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorAzulNew"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/money"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:text="@string/moneyicon"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:paddingStart="4dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/amount"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/page_padding_left"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/page_padding_left"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size"
                     />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:hint="@string/benef_reason"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorAzulNew"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/benef_reason"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:hint="@string/benef_reason2"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_padding_top_small"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColorAzulNew"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/benef_reason2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="25"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/page_margin_left"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cmdLogin"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/page_margin_right_double"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/page_margin_left_double"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@mipmap/btnconfirmacion"
            android:onClick="goToNextStep"
            android:paddingLeft="-40dp"
            android:paddingStart="-40dp"
            android:paddingRight="-5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="-5dp"
            android:text="@string/transfer_next"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDarkGreen"
            android:textSize="@dimen/simple_text_size_very_small"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Al hacer foco en alguna caja de abajo y al scrollear el fondo azul con el claro parpadea haciendo un efecto bastante molesto?? 
EJEMPLO EN FOTOS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo de tu componente?

Answer (score 0):

Revisando tu layout, lo que provoca el "parpadeo" que en realidad es un efecto visual y el cual puede no ocurrir en todos los dispositivos, se debe principalmente a que en algunos layout usas como fondo imágenes y no colores, por ejemplo:

```
<RelativeLayout
                ...
                ...
                ...
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_white">
```

En este caso, te sugiero usar colores, definelos en `colors.xml`:

```
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

y agrega la referencia al layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
                ...
                ...
                ...
                android:background="@color/white">
```